# Can I create a pull to refresh for UIViewController instead of UITableViewController in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, view

I've got a simple app that have no need to be constructed with UITableViewController. Is there any chance to create 'pull to refresh' functionality for the simple UIViewController?

Comment: Yes, but you'll have to "roll your own" or find a third-party library to help you.

Answer (score 15):

Yes, there is. In fact, in order to use `UIRefreshControl` there is only one requirement - you can place `UIRefreshControl` inside of `UIScrollView` or its subclass (for example `UITableView` or `UICollectionView`).

Example code in *Swift*:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    //...
    let refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
    refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didPullToRefresh), forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)

    scrollView.addSubview(refreshControl)
}

func didPullToRefresh() {

}
```

Example code in *Objective-c*:

```c
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    //...

    UIRefreshControl *refreshControl = [UIRefreshControl new];
    [refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(didPullToRefresh) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

    [self.scrollView addSubview:refreshControl];
 }

 - (void)didPullToRefresh
 {

 }
```

Comment: Where do you get a scrollView in a UIViewController?

Comment: You need to create one and add it as a subview.

Answer (score 6):

As of iOS 6 there is a `refreshControl` property on `UIScrollView` (and hence it's subclasses, `UITableView` and `UICollectionView`).

Code from the Apple documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uirefreshcontrol#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIRefreshControl

```
func configureRefreshControl () {
   // Add the refresh control to your UIScrollView object.
   myScrollingView.refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
   myScrollingView.refreshControl?.addTarget(self, action:
                                      #selector(handleRefreshControl),
                                      for: .valueChanged)
}

@objc func handleRefreshControl() {
   // Update your content…

   // Dismiss the refresh control.
   DispatchQueue.main.async {
      self.myScrollingView.refreshControl?.endRefreshing()
   }
}
```